# Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME default layout for UK extended keyboard

Tags: gnome, 20.04, keyboard-layout

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with keyboard "English (UK, extended, with Win keys)".

I'm confused about where to find certain characters. For example, AltGr+1 gives superscript 1, AltGr+3 gives superscript 3, so why doesn't AltGr+2 give superscript 2? Superscript 2 (meaning squared) is *much* more useful than 1 or 3. Where can I find superscript 2 on this keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that layout it's replaced with `dead_diaeresis`.

Superscript 2 is available in the basic *English (UK)* layout, and also in *English (UK, intl., with dead keys)* and a few other. So if easy access to superscript 2 is important to you, you may either want to consider to use one of those instead, or edit the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` file and replace `dead_diaresis` in the *English (UK, extended, with Win keys)* layout with `twosuperior`.